# How to Load RTF file to RichTextBox without loosing content format VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'am trying to load .rtf file created by word 2013 into richtextbox, but i have problem with content format..i have try this code..

```
RichTextBox1.LoadFile(App_Path & "/Artikel/Profile/Info Num1.rtf", RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText)
```

the content displayed but the content format is missing...

then i try yhis code to...

```
Dim SR As StreamReader
SR = File.OpenText(App_Path & "/Artikel/Profile/Info Num1.rtf")
RichTextBox1.Rtf = SR.ReadToEnd
SR.Close()
```

the content is displayed and text format is diplayed well but the table and image is irregular..

for simple question how to load .rtf file to richtextbox without loosing content format including table and image format?

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to upgrade your RichTextBox component:

```
public class RichBoxEx : RichTextBox {

  [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
  private static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string lpFileName);

  protected override CreateParams CreateParams {
    get {
      var cp = base.CreateParams;
      if (LoadLibrary("msftedit.dll") != IntPtr.Zero) {
        cp.ClassName = "RICHEDIT50W";
      }
      return cp;
    }
  }
}
```

and load the file with the safer version of Path.Combine:

```
richBoxEx1.LoadFile(Path.Combine(App_Path, @"Artikel/Profile/Info Num1.rtf"));
```

Some features will get dropped, since the RichTextBox doesn't have support for Header and Footers, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on RTF version. The version that you are using in RichTextBox control is RTF 1.6 and it may be different than your Microsoft Office Word Application. Obviously, you cannot use the feature that has been added in later version.

1. Version timeline[edit]
2. 1987: RTF 1.0
3. January 1994: RTF 1.3
4. September 1995: RTF 1.4
5. April 1997: RTF 1.5
6. May 1999: RTF 1.6
7. August 2001: RTF 1.7
8. April 2004: RTF 1.8
9. March 2008: RTF 1.9.1

The RichTextBox is supports the older version of RTF format. This control will not supports all type of formatting created in Microsoft Word. Becausae the RTF version can be different.

Microsoft Office uses following version of Rich Text Format that cannot be supported in RichTextBox control.

- Microsoft Office Word 2000 : RTF v. 1.7
- Microsoft Office Word 2003 : RTF v. 1.8
- Microsoft Office Word 2007 and above : RTF v. 1.9.1

Read more about the RTF format and its version on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format)