# Keep formatting of copied text from another application using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, clipboard

I have a little program I have written that sits in the system tray and when clicked will print the selected text(Highlighted by user) of a specific application.This bit works ok and I can get it to print out but it loses the formatting.

I have searched this sight and a lot of others trying to find out how to set the formatting properties of the copied data but am coming up empty.

Here is the code I am using at the moment:-

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles    Button1.Click

    Dim hWnd As IntPtr = FindWindow("putty", Nothing)

    EnableWindow(hWnd, True)

    Clipboard.Clear()

    SendKeys.Send("^c")
    If Clipboard.GetDataObject().GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text) Then

        RichTextBox1.Text = Clipboard.GetDataObject().GetData(DataFormats.Text) '.ToString()
    Else
        RichTextBox1.Text = "The clipboad does not contain any text"
    End If

    RichTextBox1.Paste()


    Dim result As DialogResult = PrintDialog1.ShowDialog()

    ' If the result is OK then print the document. 
    If (result = DialogResult.OK) Then


        docToPrint.Print()
    End If



End Sub
```

Basically I just want it to take a sort of snapshot of the selected text and print it out.

We used to use Clip.exe from NetadminTools.com but I am unable to get it to work on Windows 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching around a bit more I came across the following post :

[How to Load RTF file to RichTextBox without loosing content format VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25802033/how-to-load-rtf-file-to-richtextbox-without-loosing-content-format-vb-net)

and I noticed that they used RichTextBox1.Rtf instead of RichTextBox1.text. As soon as I changed this all was working as it should.

Answer (score 0):

You're only going to get plain text from putty so I'm not sure what you are expecting here.
But the CF_TEXT clipboard format (presumably what you're getting when you ask for DataFormats.Text) contains no formatting. Just the text.  If you want fonts, margins, bold/itallic/underline, colors, etc., then you need CF_RTF or CF_HTML, or one of the OLE formats.
CF_RTF is a "private" clipboard format, so you must register it in order to use it.
Start reading about clipboard formats at MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649013%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: I have just used the Putty command "Copy all to Clipboard" and pasted it into notepad to see if it messed up the formatting and it didn't. It seems to take a sort of screenshot of the terminal window. Have you any idea how I would do this with vb.